# Magento create "Newest Products" collection

Tags: magento

I'm trying to acheive a collection containing the newest products on home page.  This is my code so far:

```
$_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$_productCollection->clear()
 ->setPageSize(40)
 ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
 ->load();
```

This is returning 40 products but not in the correct order.

I have try so many things... Can somebody help me?

Comment: What do you consider the 'good' order? Can you give us a sample of the output that the current collection is providing? Any reason why you're ordering by `created_at` rather than `updated_at`?

Comment: A good order is the lastest product. Here's a link to the store [link](http://boutique.hhqc.com) . I'm doing created_at because i did not know about updated_date.

Comment: I have change created_at for update_at

Comment: It's seems like setOrder() is not working. Whaterver i put the order is still depend on the store default order.

Comment: I have also try ->addAttributeToSort()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is, but here's a handy debugging method to get you on your way.

You can always inspect your collection queries by using methods available in the `Zend_Db_Select` object.  In your case, for example, we can run:

```
echo (string) $_productCollection->getSelect()->assemble();
```

You could also add `true` as a parameter to your `->load()` method call, `->load(true)` to print the query out in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My exact problem is that setOrder() do not work. What i'm doing wrong? I just want to set the order by creation date. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can cheat and get a list of the IDs via a direct query in the php file:

`SELECT entity_id, sku FROM catalog_product_entity ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 0,40;`

As one would hope, the results are the same as if you order by entity_id.

Answer (score 0):

Use in your Collection the following:

```
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean the object first. To do so:

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
   ->clear()
   ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

Besides created_at you can use name, updated_at, sku and so on.

Hope it helps.